# Jquery google cdn not working

Tags: jquery

I am in Web Developer field i am trying to learn javascript i try this code to get a message in firebug console but its not working 
please assist me where i am doin wrong

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
   <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("jquery","1.12.4");
    google.setOnLoadCallback(function()
    {console.log($('#title').text());
    });
  </script>
    </head>
  <body>
      <h1 id="title">Getting Jquery</h1>
       </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want using jquery just add the jquery library in the head part of the html and work on it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
   <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function () {
         console.log($('#title').text());
       });
  </script>
    </head>
  <body>
      <h1 id="title">Getting Jquery</h1>
       </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use it like below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**For more version visit [GOOGLE JQUERY CDN](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery)**

To check if it is working or not do like below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
</head>

<style type="text/css">

</style>


<body>
<h1 id="title">Getting Jquery</h1>



<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 the_h1_text = $("h1#title").text();
 alert(the_h1_text);
 console.log(the_h1_text);
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding JQuery library or CDN as you prefer in script tag which should be inside the header section of Html.

```
    <head>
    <script src="jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    </head>
```

Hope it works.

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp